# Prevent screen recording in WordPress site

Tags: wordpress

**First of all, I am fully aware that there is nothing I can do to really prevent screen recording, and that someone who knows what they're doing will be able to record my website's screen, ***easily***.**

Having said that..

I would still like to implement basic screen recording prevention for videos, the same way Netflix and Udemy do it. I have found very little information on how to do that. Plugins I've found don't seem to work. Is this something to be done on the application (WordPress) level? Or does it have more to do with the codec of the videos and stuff? Or perhaps something to do with the web server?

I tried plugins that either didn't work or were too complicated and asked me to upload ".class" files which I'm not sure about. Either way, content creators with minimal technical abilities are going to be using my site and uploading videos, so I need the solution to be work seamlessly without needing the video uploader to interfere.

Anyway, kindly point me towards an implementable solution.

Comment: Udemy or Netflix show videos, that makes it way easier to prevent screen recording. I don't know any way to prevent screen recording for pure websites, and searching for libraries or plugins is officially off-topic on StackOverfliw

Comment: I am also showing videos, I have edited my question to reflect that.

Answer (score -1):

A browser cannot detect if it's being recorded or not.

If a browser could detect external applications on your PC, It would be a massive security risk.

However, assuming you want to display videos, you might want to look into **DRM (Digital Rights Management)** players. While not exactly "easy" to implement, they might be the closest you can get to when it comes to preventing people from recording your videos. Netflix (and most major streaming sites) also use
DRM players.

Here are some articles that might help you better understand the concept of DRM:

[An introduction to Encrypted Media Extensions (web.dev)](https://web.dev/eme-basics/)

[How Encrypted Media Extensions work at a more lower level (W3C)](https://w3c.github.io/encrypted-media/)